# How to get CSV dimensions from terminal

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, csv, dimensions

Suppose I'm in a folder where `ls` returns `Test.csv`. What command do I enter to get the number of rows and columns of `Test.csv` (a standard comma separated file)?

Comment: There is not such "command", the task is non-trivial. You have to implement some script for this.

Answer (score 25):

Try using `awk`. It's best suited for *well formatted* **csv** file manipulations.

```
awk -F, 'END {printf "Number of Rows : %s\nNumber of Columns = %s\n", NR, NF}' Test.csv
```

`-F,`  specifies `,` as a field separator in *csv* file.

At the end of file traversal, `NR` and `NF` have values of number of rows and columns respectively

---

Another quick and dirty approach would be like

```
# Number of Rows
cat Test.csv | wc -l

# Number of Columns
head -1 Test.csv | sed 's/,/\t/g' | wc -w
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a native solution using GNU coreutils, it is worth mentioning (since this is one of the top google results for such question) that [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) puts at your disposal a command to list the headers of a csv file, whose count returns obviously the number of columns.

```
# count rows
xsv count <filename>

# count columns
xsv headers <filename> | wc -l
```

For big files this is orders of magnitude faster than native solutions with `awk` and `sed`.